# Need help in R finding how many seasons a player played a position

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a baseball database with thousands of observations. I need to find for how many seasons a player played a position.

In the sample input, I have narrowed the positions to one (SS for shortstop) for one player: Jose Vizcaino.

**Sample input**
[image]

In his career, he played shortstop in 18 seasons; however, in two seasons, 2000 and 2006 (2006 not shown), he played the position for two different teams during the same year. My code is counting 2000 and 2006 twice, giving 20 as the total seasons played, not 18. I need code that does not count multiple times seasons in which a player played the same position (e.g., shortstop) for more than one team; rather, it just counts it once.

I would prefer a DPLYR solution but am open to others.

I have searched stackoverflow for a solution that matches my problem, but was unable to find one. If one exists, I would appreciate it if you could send me its link.

**Code used**

```
df |>
  filter(playerID == "vizcajo01", POS == "SS") |>
  
  arrange(yearID) |>
  add_count(playerID, name = "Seasons") |>
  relocate(Seasons, .after = playerID) |>
  relocate(nameFirst, .after = playerID) |>
  relocate(nameLast, .after = nameFirst) |>
  relocate(yearID, .after = playerID) |>
  relocate(POS, .after = yearID) |>
  select(playerID, yearID, POS, teamID, Seasons, nameFirst, nameLast)
```

**dput**

```
structure(list(playerID = c("vizcajo01", "vizcajo01", "vizcajo01", 
"vizcajo01", "vizcajo01", "vizcajo01", "vizcajo01", "vizcajo01", 
"vizcajo01", "vizcajo01", "vizcajo01", "vizcajo01", "vizcajo01", 
"vizcajo01", "vizcajo01", "vizcajo01", "vizcajo01", "vizcajo01", 
"vizcajo01", "vizcajo01"), yearID = c(1989L, 1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 
1993L, 1994L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2000L, 
2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2006L), POS = c("SS", 
"SS", "SS", "SS", "SS", "SS", "SS", "SS", "SS", "SS", "SS", "SS", 
"SS", "SS", "SS", "SS", "SS", "SS", "SS", "SS"), teamID = c("LAN", 
"LAN", "CHN", "CHN", "CHN", "NYN", "NYN", "CLE", "SFN", "LAN", 
"LAN", "NYA", "LAN", "HOU", "HOU", "HOU", "HOU", "HOU", "SLN", 
"SFN"), Seasons = c(20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L), nameFirst = c("Jose", 
"Jose", "Jose", "Jose", "Jose", "Jose", "Jose", "Jose", "Jose", 
"Jose", "Jose", "Jose", "Jose", "Jose", "Jose", "Jose", "Jose", 
"Jose", "Jose", "Jose"), nameLast = c("Vizcaino", "Vizcaino", 
"Vizcaino", "Vizcaino", "Vizcaino", "Vizcaino", "Vizcaino", "Vizcaino", 
"Vizcaino", "Vizcaino", "Vizcaino", "Vizcaino", "Vizcaino", "Vizcaino", 
"Vizcaino", "Vizcaino", "Vizcaino", "Vizcaino", "Vizcaino", "Vizcaino"
)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: The `dput` output is incomplete so it cannot be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select distinct rows first, then group by player and position

```
dat %>% 
  distinct(playerID, yearID, POS) %>% 
  count(playerID, POS)
```

Output:

```
   playerID POS  n
1 vizcajo01  SS 18
```